# What is the locus of $H$?

Tags: geometry, locus

Given a circle of radius $r$ and a chord $AB$ of length 1 unit, let $C$ be a variable point on the circle; let $I$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and let $H$ be the intersection of the line perpendicular to $AC$ from I. What is the locus of $H$?
[image: Figure]

Comment: The angle at the left of the triangle isn't constant at 67.57, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a circle of center $O$, an arc $AB$ fixed, and a variable point $C$ on the circle.
We draw $M$ the midpoint of $BC$, from $M$ draw $MH$ perpendicular to $AC$.
To find: The locus of $H$
Let arc $AB = 2\alpha$ which is constant
Angle $\widehat{ACB}$ = $\alpha$
Draw a circle of diameter $OB$ which passes through $M$ and through $E$ the midpoint of $AB$
Produce $HM$ to cut this circle at $I$
Angle $\widehat{CMH} = 90-\alpha$
Angle $\widehat{IMB} = 90 - \alpha$
Arc $BI$ = 180 - $2 \alpha$ which is constant, so $I$ is fixed
The locus of $H$ is the circle of diameter $AI$.

[image: Proof]

Proof by Dr.Sami Adham

[image: Proof]

Comment: Wouls it be possible to draw again this figure in a neat fashion using GeoGebra as you have done initially ?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that in a bit.

Comment: Only one thing: $I$ and $M$ should be interchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $AB$ as the reference axis for angles ($x$ axis), and consider $A$ as the origin. Let $\theta$ be the oriented angle between $AB$ and the (moving) line $AC$.

Let $H_1$ be the (moving) projection of $B$ onto  line $AC$.

Let $D$ be the (fixed) point such that $AD$ is a diameter of the given circle.

Let $\theta_0$ be the (fixed) oriented angle between $AB$ and $AD$.

The locus of $H_1$ is the circle with diameter $AB$ which has the following polar equation:

$$r=r_1=\cos(\theta).$$

By definition, the locus of $C$ is the initial circle, with polar equation

$$r=r_2=D_1 \cos(\theta-\theta_0).$$

for a certain fixed $D_1$ (the length of the circles' diameter, $AD$), and a certain fixed $\theta_0$ (which is the angle between $AB$ and $AD$).

$I$, being the midpoint of $H_1$ and $C$ (by Thales' theorem), has the following polar equation:

$$r=(r_1+r_2)/2 \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ r=(D_1\cos(\theta-\theta_0)+cos (\theta))/2$$

which can be transformed (by expanding $\cos(a-b)=\cos a \sin b + ...$) into an expression:

$$r=p cos(\theta)+q \sin(\theta)$$

which itself is known to be amenable (by taking $\delta:=\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$) to the form

$$r=\delta cos(\theta-\theta_1)$$

for a certain fixed angle $\theta_1$, which means that the locus is a certain circle passing through $A$ and, as one can verify immediately, passing as well through $B$ (for $\theta=0$).

Comment: I don't really understand what $H_1$ is, and how it relates to H in my figure.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. But where do I go from getting the equation of I to getting the equation of H?

Comment: The main thing to undersand is that everything is "drived" by polar angle $\theta$=oriented moving angle between $AB$ and $AC$. Thus $H_1,H$ and $I$ have the same polar angle, with $r=AH_1$ for the first circle, $r=AI$ for the intial (big) circle, then it is natural to say that $r=(AH-1+AI)/2$ is the length of $AH$. This is what I do.

Comment: Could you explain the equations? I understood the first sentences, but I don't really understand the rest.

Comment: Have a look at my recent improvements to the text.

Comment: Why do we need Theta 0 or 1? And is the polar equation of I the same as H? Sorry for not understanding.

Comment: Let us compare equation $r=r_1=\cos(\theta)$ with an $r$ which is at its maximum when $\theta=0$ (because $\cos(...)=1$ then), and equation $r=r_2=...$ with an $r$ that is maximum, not for $\theta=0$ but when $\theta=\theta_1$, otherwise said when  $\theta-\theta_1=0$, and in this case $\cos(\theta-\theta_1)=1$ is at its maximum. The general form of the polar equation of a circle is $r=D \cos(\theta-\theta_m)$.

Comment: Ohh, that's neat! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.  Also, what would the polar equation for H be?

Comment: As $H$ is the midpoint of $H_1$ and $C$, he polar equation for $H$ is what I have given as $r=(r_1+r_2)/2$ and subsequent computations.

Comment: Although your answer is good, I found a better proof. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I would appreciate to know it, even described in a sketchy way.

Comment: I just posted it. If you see any errors, tell me.

Comment: I don't understand why $B,I,C$ are not aligned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43599/discussion-between-namenotfoundexception-and-jeanmarie).

Answer (score 1):

Draw $BG \bot AB$ cutting $HI$ produced at $M$. Then, $AHMB$ is cyclic on the red circle. This circle cuts $BC$ at $N$.

[image]

We let $C’$ be another location of $C$. $AC’$ cuts the red circle at $H’$. $H’N$ is joined. We are going to show that $H’$ is one of the point on the locus of $H$ and that locus is the red circle.

From the fact that $\angle AH’M = 90^0$, we have $MH’ \bot AC’$. We are done if we can prove when $MH’$ cut $BC’$ at $K$ and $BK = KC’$.

By exterior angle of cyclic quadrilateral, $\alpha = \alpha_1 = \alpha_2$. This means $C’C // H’N$.

By angles in the same segment, $\beta = \beta_1 = \beta_2$. This means $KIMB$ is cyclic.

By angles in the same segment, $\gamma = \gamma_1 = \gamma_2$. This means $H’N // KI$.

Applying the intercept theorem to $\triangle BCC’$, we get $BK = KC’$