# A basic geometry problem involving circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Segment PQ is a chord common to two circles and it bisects
Angle(RPT), where R
and T lie on the circles, as shown. Each of the chords P R
and P T is cut by the other circle at points S
and U. Prove that R S = T U.

[image: Picture]

Comment: We have $RQ=QU$ and $SQ=QT$, now we only need an angle to match in triangles $QRS$ and $QUT$.

Comment: Can you shows us your effort on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that, $\angle RQU=180-\angle RPU=180-\angle SPT=\angle SQT$ and thereafter $\angle RQS=\angle UQT$.

In triangle $\triangle QRS$ and $\triangle QUT$, $QR=QU$, $QS=QT$ and $\angle RQS=\angle UQT$.

Hence,  $\triangle QRS\cong \triangle QUT$ by $S--A-S$ criteria of congruence and thereafter $RS=TU$.

Comment: @cosmo5 The answer has been edited. Thanks for pointing out but i think proving two pairs of sides in two triangles and their adjacent angles same proves it.

Comment: Agreed. Showing that the two triangles are similar first by angle chasing and then arguing they are congruent because of equal segments is more natural. +1

Comment: @cosmo5 Yes, but i think complete angle chasing is not necessary in this case. Thanks !

Comment: @limestone See my answer.

Comment: You cannot apply directly SAS property here because theAngle is not in between the equal "Sides". See the answer of Parcly Taxel [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4647370/305862).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Particular case: the center of one circle is on the bisector and that of other circle is on the big ray of the angle (RPT):

Right angle triangle QSP and QPT are equal, so $QT=QS$.Arcs QS and QU are equal , so $\angle SOQ=\angle QOU$ so in circle centered on O $QR=QU$, hence right angle triangles QRS and QTU are equal which results in the equality of TU and RS.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This curious property can be explained in a completely different way, by using polar equations of circles. Let us take $P$ as the origin and $PQ$ as the reference axis.

The polar equations of the two circles passing through the origin are

$$\begin{cases}r=d_1\cos(\theta-\theta_1)
\\r=d_2\cos(\theta-\theta_2)\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

where $d_1=PA_1$, resp. $d_2=PA_2$, are the diameters of the two circles obtained for polar angles $\theta=\theta_1$, resp. $\theta=\theta_2.$

We are interested by the absolute value of the difference between these two radii :

$$\Delta(\theta):=|d_1 \cos(\theta-\theta_1)-d_2\cos(\theta-\theta_2)|\tag{2}$$

Besides,

$$PQ=d_1 \cos \theta_1 = d_2 \cos \theta_2\tag{3}$$

Plugging the expression of $d_2$ issued from (3) into (2) gives :
$$\Delta(\theta)=|d_1\cos(\theta-\theta_1)-\frac{d_1 \cos \theta_1}{\cos \theta_2}\cos(\theta-\theta_2)|$$

Otherwise said :

$$\Delta(\theta)=\frac{d_1}{\cos \theta_2}|\cos(\theta_2)\cos(\theta-\theta_1)-\cos \theta_1 \cos(\theta-\theta_2)|$$

Using addition formulas, we finaly get, after simplification  :

$$\Delta(\theta)=\frac{d_1 |\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)|}{\cos \theta_2}|\sin(\theta)|\tag{4}$$

The fact that $\Delta(-\theta)=\Delta(\theta$) explains the equality of chords' lengths $RS$ and $TU$ in general.

Comment: I had used this kind of technique in an (old !) answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1885178/305862).

Comment: This kind of technique is used also in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3936750/305862)